# How to set text at the head of a RibbonApplicationMenu

Tags: wpf, ribbon, ribbon-control, ribboncontrolslibrary

I'm trying to have text in the top level of a RibbonApplicationMenu (trying to the get the word `File` there similar to Word or Outlook).  It seems the `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.RibbonApplicationMenu`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonapplicationmenu.aspx)

supports a `SmallImageSource` but no text property. Setting the `Label` property doesn't work for this problem.

```
xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"    
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu Label="File"><!--doesn't set the label -->
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
```

The goal is to have the word "File" appear in the circled area below.

[image: RibbonApplicationMenu]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest solution (to me) was to insert a [DrawingImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx) with a [GlyphRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrun.aspx) inside.  On a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712202/draw-formatted-text-within-a-drawingimage) is asked how to get the AdvanceWidths and GlyphIndicies for the GlyphRun.  The result is below

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.SmallImageSource>
    <DrawingImage>
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <GlyphRunDrawing ForegroundBrush="White">
                <GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
                    <GlyphRun
                            CaretStops="{x:Null}" 
                            ClusterMap="{x:Null}" 
                            IsSideways="False" 
                            GlyphOffsets="{x:Null}" 
                            GlyphIndices="41 76 79 72" 
                            FontRenderingEmSize="12" 
                            DeviceFontName="{x:Null}" 
                            AdvanceWidths="5.859375 2.90625 2.90625 6.275390625">
                        <GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                            <GlyphTypeface FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\SEGOEUI.TTF"/>
                        </GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
                    </GlyphRun>
                </GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
            </GlyphRunDrawing>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.SmallImageSource>
```

Resulting Ribbon:

[image: GlyphRun Result]

Comment: But how do you make it your own custom text be the right size?

I tried:

GlyphIndices="43 72 79 79 82 3 58 82 85 79 71" 
AdvanceWidths="9.62666666666667 7.41333333333333 2.96 2.96 7.41333333333333 3.70666666666667 12.5866666666667 7.41333333333333 4.44 2.96 7.41333333333333" 

And it is "Hello World" .. but it is super tiny.

Comment: This is clearly something that needs to be fixed... it SHOULD just be:  Label="File"

Comment: @00jt +1. I can't believe I have to put this filthy thingy to get something so simple to work (I'm not saying the answer isn't good. I actually think it's awesome and sophisticated, it's just that Microsoft really blew it here).

Answer (score 14):

Remove the unwanted elements for the visual tree, and replace them with a TextBlock that takes the text from the Label property. You have to do this for both the button on the main visual tree and on the popup's visual tree. Finally, since text is more intricate than the typical image, it is helpful to back off on the aero highlighting effects.

To use the following code, assign a name to the application menu in the XAML and call `ReplaceRibbonApplicationMenuButtonContent` with it from the Loaded event handler of the window.

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces the image and down arrow of a Ribbon Application Menu Button with the button's Label text.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="menu">The menu whose application button should show the label text.</param>
/// <remarks>
/// The method assumes the specific visual tree implementation of the October 2010 version of <see cref="RibbonApplicationMenu"/>.
/// Fortunately, since the application menu is high profile, breakage due to version changes should be obvious.
/// Hopefully, native support for text will be added before the implementation breaks.
/// </remarks>
void ReplaceRibbonApplicationMenuButtonContent(RibbonApplicationMenu menu)
{
    Grid outerGrid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(menu, 0);
    RibbonToggleButton toggleButton = (RibbonToggleButton)outerGrid.Children[0];
    ReplaceRibbonToggleButtonContent(toggleButton, menu.Label);

    Popup popup = (Popup)outerGrid.Children[2];
    EventHandler popupOpenedHandler = null;
    popupOpenedHandler = new EventHandler(delegate
    {
        Decorator decorator = (Decorator)popup.Child;
        Grid popupGrid = (Grid)decorator.Child;
        Canvas canvas = (Canvas)popupGrid.Children[1];
        RibbonToggleButton popupToggleButton = (RibbonToggleButton)canvas.Children[0];
        ReplaceRibbonToggleButtonContent(popupToggleButton, menu.Label);
        popup.Opened -= popupOpenedHandler;
    });
    popup.Opened += popupOpenedHandler;
}

void ReplaceRibbonToggleButtonContent(RibbonToggleButton toggleButton, string text)
{
    // Subdues the aero highlighting to that the text has better contrast.
    Grid grid = (Grid)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(toggleButton, 0);
    Border middleBorder = (Border)grid.Children[1];
    middleBorder.Opacity = .5;

    // Replaces the images with the label text.
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)grid.Children[2];
    UIElementCollection children = stackPanel.Children;
    children.RemoveRange(0, children.Count);
    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock(new Run(text));
    textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.White;
    children.Add(textBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Right. If you want no code-behind and no complex glyph computations, use the following XAML:

```
<RibbonApplicationMenu.SmallImageSource>
  <DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
      <GeometryDrawing>
        <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20"></RectangleGeometry>
        </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
          <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <TextBlock Text="File" FontSize="16" Foreground="White" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
          </VisualBrush>
        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
      </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
  </DrawingImage>
</RibbonApplicationMenu.SmallImageSource>
```

Advantages of this approach:

- XAML-only, no code-behind
- No glyph measurement
- Easy to change label

Comment: A nice solution, and simpler than the accepted answer, but it still suffers from the same problem of the text not being the same size as the text in the `RibbonTab`s. The correct way to do this in WPF, as always and albeit far more verbose, is to replace the default `ControlTemplate` for the menu. +1 all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Tricky! You might have to replace the **PART_ToggleButton** of the template with your own version to be able to set the text.

Using the WPF Vizualizer shows that the template contains a StackPanel with an Image and a Path (DownArrow), but no TextBlock, so I doubt that there is a place in the current control to specify the label text.

Of course, you could also **create an image that contains the desired text**.

Comment: I considered creating an Image that contains just the text "File" a bit of a hack but it would probably work.

Comment: It's worth noting the many downsides of the hack: Text will look fuzzy at DPIs other than 96; ClearType text adjustments will not work; more difficult to localize; won't worth with screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do so is just using a grid and paint a TextBlock at the right place. Be sure to make the TextBlock NOT HitTestVisible.

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
         <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top">
             <!-- your ribbon stuff -->
         </ribbon:Ribbon>
         <!-- your other stuff -->
    </DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Margin="3,26" Foreground="White"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               Text="{LocalizeExtension:LocText Key=FILE, Dict=Strings, Assembly=YourAssembly}"/>
</Grid>
```

Advantages:

- less xaml
- way easier to localize

Disadvantage:
 - looks less nice on Windows XP

Comment: I tried your option, but when i click on the RibbonApplicationMenu the text is hidden.  It only shows "File" if it isn't displaying the drop-down menu.

Comment: you are right about that... you could again use a TextBlock at the appearing RibbonMenu but I personelly did not thought that to be very important

Answer (score 0):

The following solution was posted [on an MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a09e1e42-af43-4944-8f2a-466c1f666d2c/ribbonapplicationmenu-label?forum=wpf). It involves altering the style used in the default (?) theme.

> I checked the source code of the Ribbon controls (please download the
>   [MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples from web site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4)). In the
>   theme file
>   (`\MicrosoftRibbonForWPFSourceAndSamples\RibbonControlsLibrary\Themes\Generic.xaml`)
>   of the ribbon, you could find this style "`&#220;`" is used to the
>   `RibbonApplicationMenu`. In this style, there is no element to display
>   the Text, it only has one Image element to display the image.
>
> Fortunately, we could modify the style code and add some controls in
>   the "`&#220;`"  style. Please below code:
>
> line 7264, change the code:
>
> ```
>  <!--<Image IsHitTestVisible="False"
>     Source="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType ={x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu}},
> ```
>
> Path=SmallImageSource}"
>           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
>           VerticalAlignment="Center"
>           Width="16"
>           Height="16"
>           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
>           RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />-->
>
> line 7433, add code `Label="{TemplateBinding Label}"` in the end of
>   the `RibbonToggleButton` element:
>
> ```
>  ......
>  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu}">
>    <Grid Focusable="False"
>       x:Name="OuterGrid"
>       SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
>      <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton x:Name="PART_ToggleButton" 
>        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
>        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
>        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"                       
>        Style="{StaticResource &#220;}"
>        FocusVisualStyle="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualStyle}"
>        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}"
>        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"
>        ToolTipTitle="{TemplateBinding ToolTipTitle}"
>        ToolTipDescription="{TemplateBinding ToolTipDescription}"
>        ToolTipImageSource="{TemplateBinding ToolTipImageSource}"
>        ToolTipFooterTitle="{TemplateBinding ToolTipFooterTitle}"
>        ToolTipFooterDescription="{TemplateBinding ToolTipFooterDescription}"
>        ToolTipFooterImageSource="{TemplateBinding ToolTipFooterImageSource}"
>        SmallImageSource="{TemplateBinding SmallImageSource}"
>        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay}"
>        Label="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
> ```
>
> line 7564, add code `Label="{TemplateBinding Label}"` in the end of
>   the `RibbonToggleButton` element:
>
> ```
> ......
> <Canvas>
>   <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton x:Name="PART_PopupToggleButton"
>     AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
> ```
>
> Path=(AutomationProperties.Name)}"
>           Canvas.Top="-24"
>           Canvas.Left="3"
>           IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDropDownOpen}"
>           BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
>           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
>           BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
>           Style="{StaticResource Ü}"
>           Focusable="False"
>           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}"
>           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}" 
>           Label="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
>       And in the RibbonWindow, we could set the Label property of the RibbonApplicationMenu as:
>
> ```
> <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu Label="File">
> ```

The forum post did include a ZIP of the modified sources, but the link no longer works.