# Draw formatted text within a DrawingImage

Tags: wpf, drawing

I'm trying to include some formatted text as part of a drawing in XAML.  Is this possible? How is it done?

Example:

```
<DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
      <!-- Can text be drawn here? -->
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Use a [GlyphRunDrawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrundrawing.aspx) as part of the DrawingGroup or as the Drawing itself, that is the source of your DrawingImage.  To construct the GlyphRun in Xaml is possible, and also in code behind:

```
Typeface typeface = new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretches.Normal);
if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out _glyphTypeface))
    return;

_glyphIndexes = new ushort[text.Length];
_advanceWidths = new double[text.Length];

double textWidth = 0;
for (int ix = 0; ix < text.Length; ix++)
{
    ushort glyphIndex = _glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[ix]];
    _glyphIndexes[ix] = glyphIndex;

    double width = _glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * FontSize;
   _advanceWidths[ix] = width;

   textWidth += width;
   double textHeight = _glyphTypeface.Height * FontSize;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful.  I've seen the examples in XAML but I can't see how to connect the AdvanceWidths and Height.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by connect them?

Comment: In your code-behind above the AdvanceWidths and glyphIndicies are set in a for loop.  I would have no idea how to represent that in XAML.

Comment: In Xaml they are just as a list of numbers in quotes: GlyphIndices="43 72 79" AdvanceWidths="9.62 7.41 2.96"

Comment: I saw that in the MSDN documentation.  Any idea how to figure out the "correct" values?  I've figured out the Inidicies for my text but have no idea how to get the AdvanceWidths for the various characters in my font (Segoe UI).

Comment: That's why I included the codebehind for you.  You could insert a System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine for each value calculated and grab the results from the debugger output window.

Answer (score 9):

```
<DrawingImage>
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,10,10"></RectangleGeometry>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                <VisualBrush>
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock  Text="Tyco" FontSize="16" FontWeight="999" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

Comment: But how to properly set RectangleGeometry to avoid text stretching?

Comment: Nice answer. I think this is the best solution to do it with xaml. Thanks