# Microsoft Ribbon for WPF: ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu issue

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, ribboncontrolslibrary

Using the excellent [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/08/02/announcing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf-rtw) for .NET 4 (not the .NET 4.5 build in class) I'm trying to achieve a ribbon like in Office 2010:

[image: Office 2010 Ribbon]

However I cannot get the **File** text to be shown on the *ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu*.

If I change the project Wizard generated code from

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Resources\SmallIcon.png">
```

to

```
<ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu KeyTipService.KeyTip="F" Label="File">
```

I get this:

[image: My Ribbon]

Notice that the text **File** is not shown. What am I missing?

Comment: The Ribbon for WPF is more like the Office 2007 style rather than the 2010 style. You'll need to use something like [Fluent](http://fluent.codeplex.com/) to achieve the 2010 style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set text at the head of a RibbonApplicationMenu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698191/how-to-set-text-at-the-head-of-a-ribbonapplicationmenu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you will have to use GlyphRun to display custom text in the head of RibbonApplicationMenu. Please refer to the accepted answer on thread [How to set text at the head of a RibbonApplicationMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698191/how-to-set-text-at-the-head-of-a-ribbonapplicationmenu)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft needs to fix this. It should work by just setting the "Label" as you described.

EDIT:

I just realized that Microsoft isn't even using the RibbonApplicationMenu...

Look at the following images again:

[image: Office 2010 Ribbon]

[image: My Ribbon]

Microsoft Word is using just a Tab, and turning it blue! (something i haven't figured out how to do)
They really should fix this!

Also, I noticed that Microsoft's blog on the topic just uses Icons:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf.aspx